# Provide the range of real $m$ such that $\sin{(x-\pi)} = 3 -2m$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the range of real $m$ such that $\sin{(x-\pi)}=3-2m$.

Comment: i tried to isolate m but couldn't any good results

Comment: "find findfindfindfindfindfindfind " definitely good motivation to get answers.

Comment: A good place to start would be by writing down the range of the sine function.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig [-1,1] ok

Comment: Subtract three from both sides, then divide both sides by minus two.

Comment: i did it, isolate m

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put *into* $\sin$.  Its output is going to be between $-1$ and $1$.  Now $x-\pi$ can be any real value so $\sin(x-\pi)$ will have every possible output; that it's range is $[-1,1]$.  So $-1 \le 3-2m \le 1$.  So $-4\le -2m \le -2$ so $2\le 2m \le 4$ so $2\le m \le 2$.  This wasn't meant to be hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, $\sin{x}$ has a range of $[-1,1]$. Because $\sin{(x-\pi)}$ is $\sin{x}$ translated $\pi$ units to the right, it also has a range of $[-1,1]$. Now, let us solve $\sin{(x-\pi)}=3-2m$ for $m$:

$$\sin{(x-\pi)}=3-2m\Rightarrow$$$$2m=3-\sin{(x-\pi)}\Rightarrow$$$$\boxed{m=\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{\sin{(x-\pi)}}{2}}$$

Because $\sin{(x-\pi)}$ has a range of $[-1,1]$, $\dfrac{\sin{(x-\pi)}}{2}$ has a range of $\left[-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right]$. Therefore, the maximum value of $m$ is $\dfrac{3}{2}-\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}=2$ and the minimum value of $m$ is $\dfrac{3}{2}-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}=1$. Putting these together, we get that $\boxed{1 \le m \le 2}$.